# Screen Manager in kivy with kv file

Tags: python, kivy

this is the first question I am posting so sorry if the question is not complete.

I tried the example on kivy's official page for Screen Manager and it works, but if I try using a kv file instead of the Builder, I get a black page.

Test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Test.kv

```
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

Comment: You should formulate the title as questions or show your error somehow. To me it is not obviously clear what you want. What is your question?

Comment: Your `Test.kv` should be `test.kv` (lower case)

Comment: There should be two buttons displayed, but there is nothing displayed. Changing Test.kv to test.kv is not working.

Comment: The solution was to add buildKV = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test.py should look like:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

And your test.kv file should be:

```
#: kivy 1.10.0

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    MenuScreen:
        id: menu_screen
        name: 'menu'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    SettingsScreen:
        id: settings_screen
        name: 'settings'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'menu'
```